# Get Error Invalid Attempts to call Read when reader is closed with Ef core in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

i got error when i query to Db with ef core the is this (Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

my action code is:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<ShowQuestionViewModel> showQuestions = new List<ShowQuestionViewModel>();
            foreach(var file in SchContext.QFile)
            {
                var lesson = SchContext.lessons.Include(lesson => lesson.field).Include(lesson => lesson.level).SingleOrDefault(l => l.Id == file.Id);
             
                var SampleQ = new ShowQuestionViewModel()
                {
                    qfile = file,
                    lessonName = lesson.Name,
                    FieldName = lesson.field.Name,
                    LevelName = lesson.level.Name,
                };
                 showQuestions.Add(SampleQ);
                SchContext.Dispose();
            }
```

at first i got erorr that" There is Already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first " so becuase of that i Add MultipleActiveResualtSets=true; to my connectionstring to solve this problem  this problem is solved but then this erorr show me and i dont know what should i do ? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only my problem is that i use  SchContext.Dispose(); so when i deleted my problem solved

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: Tnks for your comment